# Constant pointers used in real-life

Tags: c++, pointers

Dear Stackoverflow community

I am trying to understand pointers better and have come across a question:

Q: When can we use a constant pointer? Give an example with a real scenario and give some code.

I had a problem trying to find and understand where a constant pointer code be used in real-life and the code involved. I am not sure if my code meets the standard of my example. I tried the following:

---

## My Answer:

## 1- Definition:

A constant pointer is a pointer that cannot change the address it is holding.

## 2- Example:

If you want to find a specific number stored in your phone`s contacts. Rather than duplicating your entire contacts list (and al its numbers) and then checking for that specific number. Just hold its address and check the original contacts list if the number is there.

## 3- Code:

```
int main(){
     const int* number = 032 ... ;
     bool found = false;

     Vector<int> contactList = { 031 ... , 032 ... , 072 ... };

     for(int i=0; i < contactList.size(); i++){
         if( *number == contactList[i]){
         valid = true;
         }
     }

     if(valid){
        cout<< "Number found"<<endl;
     } else{
        cout<< "Number NOT found"<<endl;
     }
  }
```

Comment: `const int* number = 032;` is not a valid C++, moreover `const int* number` is not a constant pointer, it is a pointer to const-qualified object so you can change the address it is holding, but can not change object stored at that address.

Comment: The closest thing to references (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/references-in-c/) are constant pointers. So if you understand why references are useful, then you can derive how you can use constant pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly a const pointer and a pointer to const are different things:

a const pointer itself is const. It cannot be pointed to anything other than the thing it is already pointing to, be the thing it points to might be altered:

```
int i = 5;
int *const p1 = &i; // a const pointer
++*p1; // valid code. i is now 6
int j = 0;
p1 = &j; // error
```

a pointer to const itself may point to different things, but it assumes everything it points to is const, so it won't allow altering them:

```
int i = 5;
const int * p2 = &i; // a pointer to const
++*p2; // error
int j = 0;
p2 = &j; // valid code. p2 is now pointing to j
```

I assume your question is "Why would anyone use a pointer which assumes everything is const?". There may be many reasons. One of them is, when you see `const int *` as a function parameter, you know this function is not going to mess with your variable. It's going to stay the same after the function returns. This is essentially why we use const anyway. We could just not change variables instead, but by declaring them as const we know compiler is going to make sure our variables are not changed by mistake or misunderstanding or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

#### Pointer to const or const pointer ?

You need to be careful about the way to define a const pointer.  Because a const pointer is not a pointer to const.

```
 static int table[10]; 
 const int* number = table;    // non const pointer to const
 int * const number2 = table;  // const pointer to non const

 number++;             // this is allowed  because the pointer is not const 
 *number += 2;         // this is NOT allowed because it's a pointer to const
 number2++;            // this is NOT allowed because the pointer is const
 *number2 +=2;         // this is allowed because the const pointer points to a non const
```

By the way, be careful with leading 0 since they mean octal notation:

```
 cout << 032 <<endl;   // displays 26 in decimal since 032 is octal notation
```

#### Pointers, addresses and values

Be aware of the difference between a pointer and the value pointed to.  Fortunately C++ protects you in forbidding this:

```
 const int* number = 032;    // compiler error
```

If you want to keep a pointer to a specific value:

```
 int myvalue=032; 
 const int* number = &myvalue;     // ok as long as you remain in scope
```

#### Caution when pointing to vector elements

Last but not the least, if you'd be tempted to use a pointer to a vector element, be aware that the address of a vector element may change (and pointers be invalid) in certain cases, for example when the vector needs to grow.

#### Example of what you're trying to do

Now let's put all this together, and here a slightly modified program:

```
const int * number;    // const to avoid accidental overwrite
int search;            // value to search for
cout<<"What number are you looking for ? "; 
cin>>search;  

for(int i=0; i < contactList.size(); i++){
     if( contactList[i] == search){  // compare values
         number = &contactList[i];   // set pointer
         found = true;
     }
 }
 // if the vector is not modified,  you may use the pointer.  
 if(found){
    cout<< "Number found: "<< *number <<endl;
 } 
 else{
    cout<< "Number NOT found"<<endl;
 }
```